# Where can I find vendor neutral info and best practices on MFA using mobile?

Tags: authentication, mobile, multi-factor

I am looking for above information from both developer and architect perspectives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guidelines on multi factor authentication and authentication in general you can refer to [NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Identity Guidelines](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#post-enroll-bind)

This details standard options which can be used and preferred options.

More details can be found on section 4.1.1 Permitted Authenticator Types.

1. [5.1.5.1 Multi-Factor OTP Authenticators](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#multifactorOTP)
2. [5.1.8.1 Multi-Factor Cryptographic Software Authenticators](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#mfcs)
3. [5.1.9.1 Multi-Factor Cryptographic Device Authenticators](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#mfcd)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try reading the [SANS Reading Room](https://www.sans.org/reading-room) white papers related to such topic. Many authors list different tools that focus on the objective.